# AWS Lambda to Firestore error: cannot import name 'cygrpc'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-firestore

On my AWS Lambda Python 3.6 function I'd like to use Google Firestore (Cloud Firestore BETA) for caching purposes, but as soon as I add

```
from google.cloud import firestore
```

to my Python script and upload ZIP to AWS Lambda function, Lambda test come back with error

```
Unable to import module 'MyLambdaFunction': cannot import name 'cygrpc'.
```

AWS CloudWatch log doesn't contain any details on the error, just that same error message.

Lambda function works great on my local dev machine (Windows 10), and I can write to Firestore fine. It also works on AWS if I comment out the import and all Firestore related lines.

Any tips how I could go about solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python client for Firestore relies on the C-based implementation of GRPC. This appears not to work by default in AWS Lambda.

Node.js users have reported similar problems and they've documented a workaround of [building a docker image](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/6443).

This should be similar to any getting any other python package that requires native code to work. Perhaps something like this method for getting [scikit to work](https://serverlesscode.com/post/scikitlearn-with-amazon-linux-container/)?

I hope this is enough to get you going in the right direction, but unfortunately I don't know anything about AWS Lambda :-(.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into same issue, i solved it by using the plugin `serverless-python-requirements` for serverless framework and passing:

```
pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
```

Essentially this installs your c-based packages (and all other packages) in a docker container where it would work and then symlinks them to your lambda fn.

A helpful guide can be found on: https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/

Plugin: https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements