# Python: google-cloud-datastore in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, grpc

Because `Google Functions` does not support Python, I was hoping to use `google-cloud-datastore` in AWS Lambda but hit the same error as 
[AWS Lambda to Firestore error: cannot import name 'cygrpc'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669176/aws-lambda-to-firestore-error-cannot-import-name-cygrpc)

1. `google-cloud-storage` works just fine in Lambda so core packaging is not the issue but could pip'ing datastore miss some dependencies ?
2. setting env.var `GOOGLE_CLOUD_DISABLE_GRPC=true` does not help as error occurs at `import` itself. I wonder if this is not a design flaw: you would want to import any gRPC-related libs **only** if enabled (which is the default). Seems `cygprc` is being loaded regardless.
3. I could try downgrade the `datastore` module to a version which only supported the `http api` but not sure which one - and that would require most likely to change `storage` version too

If we managed to get `datastore` lib to work, our next attempt will be `bigquery` - should work as doesn't use gRPC (yet?)

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue?

Comment: Sorry for delay. We have skipped datastore and set metadata on the blobs to pass along information. Besides,  Google Function now supports Python runtime so we plan on migrating.